# "Accountsd wants to use the 'iCloud' keychain"

Tags: icloud, keychain, accounts

I, too, am suddenly getting this message.  I don't see a Keychain First Aid option in Keychain, and the two Login Keychain Settings were already unlocked.  Any other ideas for what the error message is all about, and what I should do about it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't turn off iCloud Keychain, turn off iCloud and then set up iCloud again?  It's likely a bad certificate if you owe accept one time. The error message you get setting up again will be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

A reboot solved this issue for me.

I had this same pesky popup with no apparent source. There were actually two of them:

```
acountsd wants to use the "iCloud" keychain.
Address Book Source Sync wants to use the "Local Items" keychain.
```

Clicking 'cancel' on the first one would cause it to reload instantly, so there was no way to opt out of responding.

I closed all open applications and restarted, apparently resolving the issue. Several things make me nervous about this: (a) The persistent behavior of the modal, (b) the lack of clear source and reference,  and (c) the request for password on keychain which I never use. Is this a new virus?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: accountsd iCloud keychain behavior]

Answer (score 0):

Try entering your old password (assuming you just changed your password).

As I understand it, this pops up because the OS is trying to migrate your old keychain to the new one (post password change) and needs your authorization to access your keychain (thus needing your previous password to migrate to the new one).

It's a poorly thought out UX.

Answer (score -1):

Type this in the terminal:

```
security -v set-keychain-settings -t 72000 login.keychain
```